# XIPS purity requirements?

Tags: propulsion, fuel, advanced-propulsion

What purity of xenon is required for the xenon ion propulsion system?  Does the purity impact the efficiency of the engine?

Answer (score 3):

This depends on [details of the engine construction](http://descanso.jpl.nasa.gov/SciTechBook/series1/Goebel__cmprsd_opt.pdf):

> One of the major drawbacks of using BaO dispenser cathodes in electric propulsion applications is the extremely high feed gas purity specified to avoid these poisoning and tungsten-material transport issues, which has resulted in a special “propulsion-grade” xenon with 99.9995% purity to be specified by some users of these cathodes for flight.
>
> Because chemistry is involved in the formation of the low work function
>   surface, dispenser cathodes are subject to poisoning that can significantly
>   increase the work function [17]. Some care must be taken in handling the
>   inserts and in the vacuum conditions used during operation of these  cathodes to avoid poisoning by impurities in the gas that produce unreliable emission and shorten the lifetime.
>
> The most potent poisons for both (dispenser cathodes [17] and LaB<sub>6</sub> cathodes [55] -ed) cathodes are oxygen and water...
>
> Oxygen partial pressures in the 10<sup>–7</sup> torr range can completely poison the dispenser cathode at temperatures of 1100˚C...
>
> For the case of xenon ion thrusters, LaB<sub>6</sub> cathodes can tolerate the crudest grade of xenon available (~99.99% purity) without affecting the LaB<sub>6</sub> electron emission or life.